# Iterate through data and loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm attempting to create a function that iterates over a data set and uses terms from the data set to query an api. I've isolated my issue to this function. I need it to call the api using the zip code provided at least twice and then move on to the next zip code within the same region. Once it's pulled data for at least 20 zip codes within the same region I need it to move to the next region and start the process all over again. I cant quite figure out how to translate that logic into python, however. Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

```
def get_zip(data):
    df = pd.read_csv(data, converters={'zip': lambda x: '{0:0>5}'.format(x)})
    dfs = pd.DataFrame(df[['zip', 'region']])
    regions = dfs['region'].unique().tolist()

    i = 1
    while i < len(regions):
        # print(regions[i])
        zlen = len(df.zip[df.region == '%s' % regions[i]])
        print(zlen)
        print(i)
        if i in range(min(zlen, 20)):
            zipcode = df.zip[df.region == '%s' % regions[i]].iloc[i]
            i += 1
            return zipcode
        else:
            zipcode = df.zip[df.region == '%s' % regions[i]].iloc[i]
            return zipcode

get_zip(metro_data.csv)
```

metro_data.csv structure below:

```
      zip                                  region
0    29831  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
1    29129  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
2    30808  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
3    29809  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
4    29137  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
5    29851  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
6    30816  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
7    30805  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
8    29105  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
9    30426  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
10   29856  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
11   29834  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
12   29828  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
13   30812  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
800  31721                      Albany, GA Metro Area
801  39842                      Albany, GA Metro Area
802  31763                      Albany, GA Metro Area
803  31791                      Albany, GA Metro Area
804  39870                      Albany, GA Metro Area
805  31787                      Albany, GA Metro Area
806  31781                      Albany, GA Metro Area
813  27801                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
814  27804                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
815  27886                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
816  27803                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
817  27856                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
818  27891                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
819  27882                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
820  27809                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
821  27864                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
822  27557                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
```

Comment: How das `metro_data.csv` look like?

Comment: @JoergVanAken added the data. Its a small scale but should get the point across.

Comment: I think you should elaborate better your problem. What if a region has less than 20 zip codes that appears at least twice.
On the other side it seems to me that once you play from `df.groupby(["region", "zip]).size()` it shouldn be too hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

change all returns to yield

```
if i in range(min(zlen, 20)):
    zipcode = df.zip[df.cbsa_name == '%s' % regions[i]].iloc[i]
    i += 1
    yield zipcode
else:
    zipcode = df.zip[df.cbsa_name == '%s' % regions[i]].iloc[i]
    yield zipcode
```

using:

```
data=get_zip("metro_data.csv")
firstiter=data.__next__()
seconditer=data.__next__()
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you want zip codes, which appear in the same region
**at least twice**. This (more precise - `df` rows with these zip codes)
can be obtained as follows:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['region', 'zip']).filter(lambda gr: len(gr) > 1)
```

For demonstration purpose, I changed your source data, adding some repeated
zips, so that the result (for my test data) is:

```
       zip                                     region
ind                                                  
0    29831  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
1    29831  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
2    30808  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
3    30808  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
4    29137  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
5    29137  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
7    30805  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
8    30805  Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area
802  31763                      Albany, GA Metro Area
803  31763                      Albany, GA Metro Area
805  31787                      Albany, GA Metro Area
806  31787                      Albany, GA Metro Area
814  27804                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
815  27804                 Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area
```

As you can see, there are:

- 4 zips in *Augusta-Richmond* region,
- 2 zips in *Albany* region,
- 1 zip in *Rocky Mount* region.

Other zip codes are not repeated.

For demonstration purpose, I lowered the number of zips from
each region to 3 (instead of your 20).

Then, to get the "limited" list of zips, you can write:

```
df2.groupby(['region']).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(x.zip.unique()[:3]))\
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('zip')
```

getting:

```
region
Albany, GA Metro Area                        31763
Albany, GA Metro Area                        31787
Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area    29831
Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area    30808
Augusta-Richmond County, GA-SC Metro Area    29137
Rocky Mount, NC Metro Area                   27804
Name: zip, dtype: object
```

As you can see, the number of zips from *Augusta-Richmond* region
has been lowered to 3.

So now you have your zip list and can do with is whatever you want,
e.g. call some API.